# Instagram How can I get users id in Sandbox mode

Tags: android, instagram

I have a Sandbox mode and I am trying to get users "id" by tagname using:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag-name}/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

but I have the answer with only one user id:

```
{"pagination": {"next_max_tag_id": "AQA8KucI7XNxxeiRGiEg2apJpWJKClzThz1Mc1JyDrlsHcsYAFMCdz5eclSQRqI5AsrY-YW6J3bVXMQvZ1516FeCvl6cest_bbKxf8r2e3Iptw", "deprecation_warning": "next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead", "next_max_id": ...
```

But if I can't to get more users "id", for what the instagram has the  sandbox rate limit?

I need more users for testing (follow and unfollow, write  to database etc)?
Maybe, аm I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [/users/search](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_search) endpoint? That's where you can get the **User ID**.